# Tkitner label only updates the 4th label in the label loop

Tags: python, loops, tkinter, label

I am making a quiz for my cs project in school and I want to
change the labels so it will display the next set of options
in the 2D array, and this is the closest I have gotten to it,
the question label works just fine.

```
def display_options(): 
    global optionsLbl
    #try and separate 2D array disp [0] and then the    next
    global x
    for x in range(4):
        optionsLbl = Label(quiz, text = options[0][x],height = 3, width = 25, bg = ("#856ff8"))
        optionsLbl.grid(row= x+3,column=2)

        
        
def display_radiobuttons():   
    #Radio buttons 
    x = IntVar()
    for x in range(4):
        test2 = Radiobutton(quiz, value = x, bg = ("#856ff8"))
        test2.grid(row=x+3)
        
        
def nextQuestion():
    nextQ = Qdict["Q"].pop(1)
    string_variable.set(nextQ)
    
    options.pop(0)

    
    for x in range(4):
        optionsLbl.configure(text = options[0][x])
```

Comment: The problem here is that you're reassigning the labels four times. In your first loop, you use `optionsLbl = Label(...`, which is run four times (`for x in range(4)`). Thus, once the loop ends, `optionsLbl` is set to the fourth label you created. Then, later on in your code, you use `optionsLbl` as if it stored all four of the labels: `for x in range(4): optionsLbl.config(...`. What that actually does is just configure the fourth label four times. Instead of re-assigning the `optionLbl` variable, you should just append each label to a `list`.

Comment: Please provide a [mvce].

Answer (score 0):

You're only getting the last label in the for loop because you overwrite the label every iteration of the loop. You need to append the labels to a list to keep them.

```
my_labels = []
for x in range(4):
    optionsLbl = Label(quiz, text = options[0][x],height = 3, width = 25, bg = ("#856ff8"))
    optionsLbl.grid(row=x+3,column=2)
    my_labels.append(my_labels)
```

Or using list comprehension

```
my_labels = [Label(quiz, text = options[0][x],height = 3, width = 25, bg = ("#856ff8")) for x in range(4)]
for x, label in enumerate(my_labels):
    label.grid(row=x+3, column=1)
```

While this uses two loops, it is generally better to grid your widgets much later at the same time as your other widgets. Either option will work though